# Enable Button Link Only After Certain Number of Page Links are Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a web page in which a person can sign up to win door prizes, but only after they view some page information. I want the door prize button to only enable after the person clicks at least 15 links on the page (the links are fancybox modal iframe links).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can add an event listener on every link then increment a variable that count the number of click ?

Comment: You can use localstorage here to store the count of click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished simply using a counter and event listeners on your link elements:

```
let linksClicked = 0;

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a.inc-counter');

links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', incrementLinksClicked);
})
```

Full example is [here](https://codepen.io/cmaresh/pen/yLajEGY).

Answer (score 1):

This works below, you can attach the event listener to any `a` tag but you probably want to limit it to specific promotional links. This increases the variable `clickCount` and once it reaches the correct limit enables the button.

I've added a label that counts down for users, and stops once the door opens.

I've also added a reset button which an attached event trigger that resets the click count to 0 and disables the prize door button again.

The code is fully commented.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Create variable to store click counts
var clickCount = 0;
var doorRequirement = 15;

// Update label with required clicks before door opening
$(".click-count").text(doorRequirement - clickCount);

// Add event listener for links with class '.count-me'
$("a.count-me").click(function() {

  // Add one
  clickCount = clickCount + 1;

  // Check if remaining count is 0 or higher
  if (doorRequirement - clickCount >= 0) {

    // Update click count label
    $(".click-count").text(doorRequirement - clickCount);

  }

  // Check if it reaches the limit
  if (clickCount == doorRequirement) {

    // Enable continue button if it does
    $("#prizeDoor").removeAttr('disabled');

  }


});

// Reset button
$("#reset").click(function() {

  // Reset click count to 0
  clickCount = 0;

  // Update label for users
  $(".click-count").text(doorRequirement - clickCount);

  // Disable prize door button
  $("#prizeDoor").attr("disabled", "disabled");

});
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button[disabled] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a class="count-me">Count Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="count-me">Count Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="count-me">Count Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Don't Count This Link</a>
</div>

<div>
  <label><span class="click-count"></span> clicks before the prize door is open!</label>
</div>

<button id="prizeDoor" disabled="disabled">Door Prize</button>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```